# Github stats on pull requests

Tags: github

I'd like to find a way to create a report of all pull requests in a repo, and see who has reviewed this PRs. I can't seen to find a way to do this using github's api.

Comment: Is the problem listing PRs or reviewers? PRs should be here: GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls